# Is it possible to only show the calendar from the date picker?

Tags: java, javafx, datepicker

Date picker has a calendar that pops up when clicked on. Is it possible to only use the calendar that displays? If so how?

I just want to display a calendar that shows info for each date. I'm pretty new to JAVA FX.

EDIT: I kinda want something like a "CalendarView". Where I can edit content etc.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#datepicker

Comment: I guess I better read more about Java FX, because this didn't help me. Does this show the components or something?

Comment: modifying `CSS` you will be allowed to customize your `DatePicker` appearance